# Google plus & Facebook sign in not working in iOS webview

Tags: ios, webview

Same thing happened in Android & that was resolved using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.

Issue with Android webview was that it doesn't support multiple windows & pop up with Google login can't be handled.

How would I resolve this in `iOS Webview`?

Error message that is coming after Google sign in is `Please Close this Window`. And for Facebook login, no error message, `just a blank screen`.

Can someone help in this? It will be highly appreciated.